# Как настроить SSH подключение? (Connection refused)

Tags: ssh, localhost, kibana

Пытаюсь подключиться по SSH командой `ssh -p 9999 -L 5602:xx.xx.x.xxx:5601 login@zz.zzz.zzz.zzz` и потом в браузере ввожу `localhost:5602` в результате в браузере получаю

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

а в командной строке

```
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

как это исправить?

Дополнительная информация: CentOS 7, пытаюсь запустить Kibana по SSH, firewall отключен

Comment: Очевидно, `xx.xx.x.xxx:5601` отказывается принять соединение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настройки Kibana по-умолчанию разрешают приложению работать только на интерфейсе locahost.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html

Стоит поменять настройки на нужные (в частности поставить 0.0.0.0 чтоб слушать все интерфейсы) и все будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что у вас кто-то действительно слушает порт 5601 на машине xx.xx.x.xxx (но не на машине zz.zzz.zzz.zzz!)
И да, в браузере (если только он на той же самой машине, с которой вы запускаете ssh — это не очевидно) надо вводить `localhost:5602`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81878/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-prokoshev---ssh--conn).